# Waiting queue vs. Ready queue

Tags: .net

Why is there a Ready and Waiting queue for every object when using a monitor? If a thread is done with an object, just pop the next item in the Waiting queue. The Ready queue seems redundant.

The context is .NET, more specifically the monitor class.

Comment: You'll need to give context. Were you reading something when you arrived at this question? If so, link to it or repeat the context here.

Comment: "in .NET" - What class?  Monitor?  Something else?

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about Windows threading and not .NET specifically. Please clarify.

Comment: Understand how monitors work is important.  Focus on the Wait and Pulse methods, not Enter and Exit.

Answer (score 5):

A producer/consumer queue is a really good use case for learning about the Monitor class.

Assume that work is sporadically added to the queue.  Sometimes there are a lot of items needing to be processed, sometimes long periods of time will elapse with no items in the queue.

So, let's say you have k consumer threads waiting around to process items in the queue.  In other words, each thread implements a tight loop, constantly trying to

1. Request to get the `lock` on the queue (this puts you in the Monitor's "ready" queue).
2. Once you get the lock, check if the queue has any items.  If not, you have two choices for releasing the lock:
   a) Call Monitor.Exit, and then call Monitor.Enter to put yourself in the back of the "ready" queue.
   b) Or, call Monitor.Wait, and put yourself in the Monitor's "waiting" queue.

If you choose option "a", your k threads will be wasting CPU cycles moving through the ready queue over and over, finding no work to do, and starting all over again at the back of the queue.

If you choose option "b", you're saying "there's nothing here to do right now, let me sleep, and wake me up when there's something to do".

With option "b", if the queue is empty, you will soon find all of your consumers sleeping in the "waiting" queue, and no CPU time being wasted.

Then, when a producer adds an item to the queue, it calls Monitor.Pulse.  This wakes up the first thread in the "waiting" queue, which then goes to the back of the "ready" queue (which is also the front of the queue if the "ready" queue was empty).

When a thread gets the lock and consumes this item from the queue, it calls Monitor.Enter again, and goes to the back of the "ready" queue.

See [this article](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx) for a classic implementation of a producer/consumer queue in .NET.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, but your idea can be easily implemented with just the waiting queue ( the queue of sleeping threads).
Why can't a call to Monitor.Pulse just dequeue the first element of the waiting queue, i.e. why does it first have to go in the ready queue?

Comment: @user1316459 - Let's say all of the consumers are busy as more items get added to the task queue (and all of the Monitor.Pulse calls go unused, because the consumers are already awake and busy).  If there is only a waiting queue, then as each consumer finishes its current task, it will go back to sleep in the Wait queue, and there won't be any consumers awake to process the new work that came in.

Comment: @user1316459 - "but your idea can be easily implemented with just the waiting queue".  I invite you to do that, and make it public in a blog.  Maybe you'll come up with something new.  Or maybe you won't, but along the way you'll get a deep understanding of all the issues.

Comment: "If there is only a waiting queue, then as each consumer finishes its current task, it will go back to sleep in the Wait queue"
No it won't. After each consumer finishes it's work, it will try to acquire the lock. There is only 2 things that can happen here: 1. it requires the lock, takes a task and releases the lock. no problem.

2. it can't require the lock, because another consumer is currently taking a task. So, it goes in the sleeping (waiting) queue. The other consumer has now taken its' task and pulses the sleeping (waiting) queue. As a result, the original consumer can now try again.

Comment: @user1316459 - I don't see how your way could work, and the comments section of an answer isn't really the place to get into a long discussion.  But go ahead and try it out, and let everyone know if you come up with something.

Comment: Awesome article link, very detailed with examples of everything multi-threaded.  I spent hours.

Comment: @Brain2000 - Yes, that's one of my favorite articles that I've ever read.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I've understood your question properly, the two serve different purposes.

The "ready" queue is for threads which are ready to run as soon as they can obtain the lock. They're just waiting to acquire the lock. This is mostly used for mutual exclusion, to prevent two threads from both using the same resource at the same time.

The "waiting" queue is for threads which are waiting for a particular *signal* - namely the monitor being pulsed. This is often used for co-ordination - for example in a producer/consumer queue, where if the queue is empty, a consumer will wait until a monitor is pulsed before it checks the queue again. While no-one is producing and no-one is consuming, no thread owns the monitor - there's no resource in use. But the monitor is used to co-ordinate the consumer with the producer.

Comment: ...or use voodoo mind reading to figure out what the question is asking.

Comment: @TimothyShields: Well, I searched for "ready queue" and "waiting queue" and found this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12121151/monitor-pulse-wait-unexpected-behaviour - I suspect this one is using the same terminology.

Comment: So you're saying that pulse will notify the consumer whenever something is ready so in the meantime the consumer thread can do other stuff.

I don't think this is possible, because pulse only notifies threads that are in the waiting queue and these threads are already blocked so they can't do anything.

Comment: @user1316459 - "so in the meantime the consumer thread can do other stuff".  No, it's the opposite.  Threads in the waiting queue block, so they don't eat up CPU cycles getting the lock on the queue over and over to see if there is anything to consume.